# Find the limit of $x_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}+k}\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n}); n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Find the limit of $x_{n}$ $$x_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}+k}\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n}); n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$$.

The right answer should be $-\frac{1}{4\pi}$

Comment: What have you tried? And $\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: I tried to split it in two sums and I got  $x_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(\sqrt{n^{4}+k}-\sqrt{n^{4}})\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n})+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}}\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$

Answer (score 2):

Use, with $\frac kn\le 1$, that  $$
\sqrt{n^4+k}=n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}
=n^2\left(1+\frac{k}{2n^4}+O(n^{-6})\right)=n^2+\frac{k}{n^2}+O(n^{-4})
.$$ Then in the sum of the constant terms
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right)
=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (n-k)}n\right)\right]=0
$$
and in the terms linear in k in the first factor
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac kn⋅\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right)⋅\frac1n
=\int_0^1x\sin(2\pi x)\,dx+O(n^{-2})
$$
by the trapezoidal rule. Put together this should give your result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!There's no other method to solve this?I didn't learn at school about Taylor series.I mean that "O(n^-6)"...

Comment: This is the usual $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}8+...$ and using that $x=\frac{k}{n^4}=O(n^{-3})$ in the remainder term.

Comment: You can also compute without Taylor $$\sqrt{1+x}-(1+\frac x2)=\frac{-\frac{x^2}4}{\sqrt{1+x}+(1+\frac x2)}=O(x^2).$$